# How does light get from one bulb to another in a sequence of light bulb?

Tags: electricity

How does light get from one bulb to another in a sequence of light? Like in the advertisements or a smaller group? Is it the same light?

Comment: What are you talking about? Could you give an example of "a sequence of light".

Comment: Like a 10 light bulbs linked in a row and one bulb turns on one after the other to give the appearance of movement

Comment: How does the light get from one bulb to the next?

Comment: posted to thedailywtf.

Comment: ummmmm..... wut?

Comment: @DylanCleaver I think what the OP is talking about is the illusion of movement created when a series of bulbs are switched on in succession, making it seem like the light is moving from one bulb to another.

Answer (score 2):

The most convenient way to achieve a sequence of bulbs being turned on and off in a sequence, at least in my opinion, is by using a controller that you program to do so. In the end they're just individual light sources being switched on and off in a pre-established way.

For example you could take an arduino board and do something like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hn9KfJQWqgI)

Comment: the old-school way of doing it is to use a rotating pattern of electrical contacts like this: http://www.google.com/patents/US2192673

Answer (score 1):

The light itself doesn't 'move' from one bulb to another. The bulbs are switched on one-after-the-other, which makes it seem like the light is 'moving'. *How* that is done is explained by Ignacio.